# Youtube Javascript conflict Only with Safari 6

Tags: javascript, safari, youtube

I' ve got a wild Javascript conflict since my client has decided to put his videos on Youtube. It's clear the conflict occurs between the iframe's javascript and my code (only a randomized fadin on the background)... The whole page resizes weirdly as soon as the video plays. The elements in the page loose their position AND width !!! I've tried to stop my script and also to remove the iframe: The window resizes well in both cases. This is not happening with other browsers (Safari 5 neither):

Unfortunately the site's already online:

http://www.digitalvideo.fr

You can reach my script via the source code (right click).

Any help REALLY APPRICIATED !!!

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Solution found !!

For those who could be interested: 
Safari 6 dosen't have any problem dealing with z-index but, for any reason a Javasctript DOM element z-index modification while using YouTube iframe causes real problems on the displayed page (even and especially on non-modified elements).

In my case i was modifying this property on 2 div blocks.

Solved.